# Meteor Client Certificate Auto-Login

Tags: javascript, meteor, nginx, certificate

I have an nginx server verifying client CAC certificates. nginx then forwards (as an HTTP header) the client's verified username to my meteor application.

Inside my meteor applicaiton, on the server side I have

```
Meteor.onConnection(function(conn) {
    // username = conn.httpHeaders['username-from-cert']
    // If user doesn't exist, call Accounts.createUser()
    // else <-- ISSUE HERE
})
```

My issue is logging the user in once an account is created. I am creating a random password for the client (because nginx is doing my authentication for me) How do I tell the client this password, and have the client automatically login?

Goal:

1. User submits client certificate
2. Client connects to nginx server
3. nginx server forwards client's name/cert-info to meteor
4. meteor creates account if non-existant, OR auto logs-in the user.
5. client logs-in without any user interaction (other than submitting client cert)

Everything I am reading involves the user logging in from the client code, but I cannot login the user from the server. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to register your own login handler that returns a userId, similar to https://github.com/fongandrew/meteor-login-as-user. I would say just use their package, but I believe meteor packages are on their way out with a move toward NPM.

Also, make sure hat HTTP header is stripped out at the proxy so that clients don't have control over changing it...